# Heroku deploy fails because it can not find config module

Tags: express, heroku, deployment

This is the error I get in my Heroku logs: `Error: Cannot find module './config/keys'`

This is where that line in my `index.js` file comes from:

```
const keys = require('./config/keys');
```

My config folder is in the root directory and I have a `keys.js` folder in there, so I'm not sure what this error is telling me I am doing wrong, because the file is definitely there.

Comment: Do you have `keys.js` in your `.gitignore` file? The file may definitely be there, but if its being ignored, Heroku will not see it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you "have a keys.js folder in there". But if you're calling `require('./config/keys')` there should be a *file* named `keys.js`. If there is a folder named `config/keys` that contains one or more js files, you should `require` each file in that folder that you need using `require('./config/keys/filename.js');`

Comment: This answer is not an answer. When working in Nodejs you don't need to add the file extension to a require statement.

Comment: How does "you don't need to add the file extension" make this not an answer?